# Java fileinputstream using with url

Tags: java, fileinputstream

How to input in the fileinputstream, a file to url?

I enter the url in the Fileinputstream, but the output of the URL is wrong, because the link slashes are turned backwards like - from / to \ and the double slashes // are \ only one slash and backwards.Is there a way with the fileinputstream to do that ? If it isn't, can you tell me what should I use instead of fileinputstream?

Comment: are you trying to write a file from a URL to the HDD?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Showing some code would help us understand your problem.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

If you want to obtain an [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) to retrieve data from a URL, then using the [`URL.openStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) method will return an `InputStream`, which can be used like any other `InputStream`.

For example,

```
InputStream is;

// if we were getting data from a file, we might use:
is = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file");

// or, from a URL, then retrieve an InputStream from a URL
is = new URL("http://google.com/").openStream();
```

Comment: Worked.. i was trying that with the url butt..looks like i forgot the openStream, thnx

Answer (score 0):

FileInputStream can be initialized with either a path name or a file object.

If supplying a path name you should only need to convert any *back* slashes \ to double backslashes \