# Can't open a text file

Tags: java

I call function with:

```
Anagrams("http://www.puzzlers.org//pub//wordlists//unixdict.txt");
```

In the function I write:

```
public static void Anagrams(String path)
{
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```

And I get an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:\www.puzzlers.org\pub\wordlists\unixdict.txt
```

But when I put the path in a browser, the browser opens the file fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to be using an input stream reader rather than a file reader. Consult [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html).

Comment: Just a random guess. but you use "//" in your call to the function. The escape character is "\\" try that.

Comment: i tried using  input stream reader, and "\\" as eascape characters, but stillget the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java fileinputstream using with url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528388/java-fileinputstream-using-with-url)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a text file directly from Internet using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259339/how-to-read-a-text-file-directly-from-internet-using-java)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to read from a URI across the network, not a file on a local system. FileReader is the wrong tool. Create a [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) object from that string, call openStream() against that to get the network connection to it, wrap an InputStreamReader around it, and then wrap the BufferedReader around that.

See, for example, [Oracle's example in their documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)

Comment: Or, easier, OP should just Ctrl+S the file to disk.

Comment: @Boann: They'd then have to change their code to read from where they saved it on disk. And they'd have to worry about whether the saved copy was current. That may be a perfectly reasonable approach, but it didn't seem to be the question they were asking.

Comment: ‎@keshlam Yes, but there is always code to change. And there are always things to worry about. If they read it from online, they have to worry about whether the URL stays current, and whether a network connection is available, and the traffic usage, and whether the site will let them scrape that file every time their program runs, and any privacy concerns of it all.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but we agree that we disagree.